# tail -f using PuTTY hangs

Tags: ssh, putty, tail

I am using PuTTY command line to connect to a server and tail a log file. On local machine I've created a file "tail-exec" which contains following text:

`tail -f /var/log/test.log`

I am starting putty through command line as:

`putty -ssh -t -pw  -m tail-exec user@server`

This opens up the terminal window with log tail. But the problem is that this terminal hangs after there are few hundred lines added to the log.

If I open putty manually, and then run the tail command from the bash prompt, then it is not hanging for thousands of lines also.

I've tried using following text in tail-exec file, but same issue is happening:

`bash -i tail -f /var/log/test.log`

Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: Is the log textual, or do some control characters appear there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a saved session where you set the Option "**Keepalive**". The use the session like this:

```
putty -ssh -t -pw -m tail-exec -load 'session-name'
```

Comment: here's a better tutorial http://blog.nth-design.com/2010/05/10/using-keepalive-in-putty/