# putty remote log tailing hang

Tags: ssh, putty, tail

I've read [tail -f using PuTTY hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545611/tail-f-using-putty-hangs)

But please let me ask again.

1. I connect to `A` using putty.
2. Then I connect to `B` using ssh.
3. I execute `tail -f ...`

After some lines tailed terminal stops.

1. Connection is alive.
2. Enter key doesn't restart tailing
3. I have to CTRL-C and re-execute the tail command.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible (e.g. if you are tailing a log file) that the file is being *rotated*: that something renames the file and incoming data is then added to a new file with the original name.

If this is what is happening, use `tail -F ...` instead of `tail -f ...`.